# C#- Populate a treeview inside a cell dynamically in datagrid- winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, treeview

Hi I have a datagrid and would like to insert a treeview in each cell to view and select items per hierarchy level- Screenshot attached [image].

I tried to create through the following code but it shows in a wierd way and does not expand to view the child nodes:

```
 List<string> treeList = new List<string>();

 TreeView tree = new TreeView();
 tree.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Root"));
 if (treeList.Count() == 1)
  {
     tree.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(treeList[0]));
  }
 else if (treeList.Count() > 1)
  {
     tree.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(treeList[0]));
     tree.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(treeList[1]));
  }

   tree.ExpandAll();

   dgPreview.Rows.Add(tree,"");
```

The result is also attached as screenshot.[image]

Can anybody guide on the issue!!

Comment: a) - __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! b) - DatagridViewCells are no containers and creating a suitable cell type is tedious, to say the least. Consider dropping DGV for a some LayoutPanel, either TableLP or FlowLP..

Comment: Oh yes Datagridview. but this is supposed to be a new requirement for my already running project. so changing the control would be too hard!

Comment: The data in the right cells are populated based on the cells on the left so i need some control which provides a table like structure with each cell as a tree.

Comment: Nobody is a big fan of TableLayoutPanel but it does provide a grid of 'containers'. Note that its 'Cells' are no actual controls/containers but rather virtual addresses but you can drop a TreeView there or a UserControl..

Comment: Thanks i got it done..i could now add treeview to y table layout and it looks fine.!